# second image in array can be saved on localhost but first one always get 404 not found

Tags: php

i have an odd problem that i realy cant find out where is that problem..

when i use curl or file get contents or copy function to save an image from some address first image cant be saved on my server but the second one can.

for example when i use this 2 image

```
http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g2.jpg
http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g4.jpg
```

g4.jpg can be saved on my localhost but not g2 one...when i change it to

```
 http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g4.jpg
http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g2.jpg
```

i can save g2 but i cant save g4...so i think there must be a problem with first one here...but when i put many images like

```
http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g1.jpg
    http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g2.jpg
http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g3.jpg
    http://94.182.168.34/Digikala/Image/HtmlEditor/Review/2014/7/17/g4.jpg
```

some can be saved and some of these images cant

here is my code in php

```
    function  putImages($images,$id_product,$name){
        $conn = conn();
        $images = explode("\n",$images);
        $i = 1;
        $name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $name);

        foreach($images as $image){
            if(!get_headers($image, 1)){
                continue;
            }
            $header = get_headers($image, 1);

            if($header == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'){
                continue;
            }

            //$id_image is 24 for example
            $numbers = str_split($id_image,1);
            $add = 'img/p/';
            foreach($numbers as $number){
                $add .=  $number . '/';
//this will make img/p/2/4/ address for example

            }

            if (!file_exists($add)) {
                mkdir($add, 0755, true);
                }


            try {
//i put this on try block if i can find out an error beside 404 not found
                if($ch  = curl_init($image)){
                    // i actualy tryed to skip if no image found and did it without if staement too

                $new_address = $add . $id_image . '.jpg';
                copy('file/index.php', $add . 'index.php');
                $fp = fopen($new_address, 'wb');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                fclose($fp);

                }else{
                    continue;
                }

                $img = new resize($new_address);
                $img -> resizeImage(80, 80,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-cart_default' . '.jpg');
                $img -> resizeImage(250, 250,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-home_default' . '.jpg');
                $img -> resizeImage(458, 458,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-large_default' . '.jpg');
                $img -> resizeImage(125, 125,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-medium_default' . '.jpg');
                $img -> resizeImage(98, 98,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-small_default' . '.jpg');
                $img -> resizeImage(800, 800,'auto');$img -> saveImage($add . $id_image . '-thickbox_default' . '.jpg');

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $i++;
        }

    }
```

i tryed to check if my server cant find that image so skip foreach loop but no chance on that too!!

Comment: Is this a problem of getting the resource at URL (`error 404`) or saving it as a local file? The title seems to indicate this is the former. In this case, can you check the GET request content and ensure it is always correct?

Comment: just try with $i = 0; once. and tell it's working or not?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh $i = 0; not working..

Comment: @mins ofcourse problem is with getting resource because when i check header first one is always 404 not found...how can i check GET request ?

Comment: You can check GET request in two ways $_GET or $_REQUEST.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i think the problem is using textarea mayabe textarea just add some charachter like spaces or something but i tryed using trim function and no luck again..checked request and get value.. both of them returns an empty array

Comment: are you using any text ediotr?

Answer (score 0):

in this case of problem when i used textarea and typed links in textarea and explode links by "\n" to get links..those links have some whitespaces and you should trim those links.
so i just used

```
    foreach($images as $image){                 
            $image = trim(str_replace("\r", "", $image));
....
    }
```

and problem solved..do not remember to trim and replace \r because IE add \r\n and other browser add \n to each line breaks

Comment: Its really impressive that you resolve your problem yourself :).